# Business Address not showing in Google Place ID

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Apologies, I am aware this question has been asked before but I cannot seem to get any of the solutions working for me.

I am currently trying to create a review link for a business (which is set up in Google My Business) so I can create a 'write a review' button on the website. I understand I need the Place ID for this.

I have entered the businesses address into the Place ID search page but the business does not come up. It has been over a week since I submitted the business on Google My business and it says everything is verified.

Please could somebody tell me how I can get my Place ID?

The business on Google Maps: https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Little+School+Pre-School/@53.9126163,-1.7536214,15z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1slittle+school+preschool+burley+in+wharfedale!3m4!1s0x0:0x7d9cc17e53d621ae!8m2!3d53.9126365!4d-1.7448655?hl=en

The business Address: Little School Pre-School, Methodist Church, Main Street, Burley in Wharfedale, LS29 7DT.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You can try to ask in Google Maps API [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188875). I believe Googlers can find Place ID for you.

Comment: This is your Places ID: `ChIJa0Byk7j8e0gRriHWU37BnH0`

Comment: thanks so much for the help!